# Make yup validate differently depending on what function I call

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cohen-k3kdtq?file=/src/App.js Here is the codesandbox example of my code

What I need to do is when I click the 'Preview' button I want to disable validation on last two fields (price, category) and when I click 'Submit' I want to validate all the fields. I tried to change react-hook-form resolver depending on state but it doesn't let me and had an idea about making fields not required when boolean variable from component changes but I don't know how can I send this variable to yup schema

```
const nftSchema = yup.object().shape({
          NFTCollectionAddress: yup
            .string()
            .required("Collection address is required")
            .test("len", "Not a valid address", (val) => val.length === 42)
            .matches("0x", "Not a valid address"),
          NFTTokenID: yup
            .number()
            .typeError("You must specify a number")
            .required("Token ID is required"),
          price: yup
            .string()
            .required("Price is required")
            .test("inputEntry", "The field should have digits only", digitsOnly)
            .test(
              "maxDigitsAfterDecimal",
              "Number cannot have more than 18 digits after decimal",
              (number) => /^\d+(\.\d{1,18})?$/.test(number)
            ),
          category: yup.string().required("Category is required")
        });
        
    export default function App() {
      const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors }
      } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(nftSchema),
      });
      const onSubmit = (data) => {
      };
      const handlePreview = (data) => {
      };
      return (
          <form>
            <h4>Token ID</h4>
            <input
              name="NFTTokenID"
              type="text"
              {...register("NFTTokenID")}
            />
            <h4>Collection</h4>
            <input
              name="NFTCollectionAddress"
              type="text"
              {...register("NFTCollectionAddress")}
            /> 
            <h4>Price</h4>
            <input
              name="price"
              type="text"
              {...register("price")}
            />
            <h4>Category</h4>
            <input
              name="category"
              type="text"
              {...register("category")}
            />
            <button onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>Submit</button>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit(handlePreview)}>Preview</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a different schema for preview, and changing the schema passed to yupResolver based on isPreview? On Preview button also would just set the isPreview state, not use the handleSubmit function.